# Im making a program for compiler using c but the strlen function is asking for a prototype

Tags: turbo-c

I'm using pointer and the strlen function is firing an error that "strlen should have a prototype"

Comment: could u paste your code?  u need #include "string.h"

Answer (score 0):

Prototype is signature or in other words declaration of the function to tell the compiler that something like that exit. The compiler assumes at calling that the definition might be below some place of calling. This it gives an error of prototype. Consider the following template of code for explanation.

```
void fun();   //declaration/prototype
void main(){
  ...
  fun();      //calling
  ...
}
void fun(){
  ...
}
```

The above code will give the same error. Although the definition of the function fun is present in the code. In your program, you might have called `strlen` function but to use it you have to include the string.h header file.

```
#include <string.h>
```

Include this line in program at the start of your file. You can learn more about function prototype from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype) and about strlen from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/).